# Getting error when trying to flash yaml file to ESP8266

Tags: yaml

I got the yaml file from https://github.com/klaasnicolaas/home-assistant-glow/blob/main/home_assistant_glow.yaml

I added my wifi details and when I try to compile I get an error. Am I missing something?

I am quite new to this so I'm not sure if there is something that I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), include all relevant code in your question instead of linking to off-site resources, show the error you get („I get an error“ is not a problem description) and describe what you're doing (*compile* is not a usual action on a YAML file, what do you mean by that?), ideally tag all relevant technologies. We cannot help you unless you provide enough details for us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1 month ago, so I hope you have it figured out already, otherwise:

1. Install ESPHome addon in home assistant.
2. Copy the yaml file to the directory esphome in your HA installation.
3. Go to the Web UI for ESPHome addon, and select install. This will connect to your ESP and flash the program.